# Executing a function across multiple pages with pagebeforeshow jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, function, jquery-mobile

I have built a webapp where I'm running into some interesting behavior where I can't seem to get the pagebeforeshow command to execute consistently. For this example, let's say I have 3 html5 pages (page1, page2 and page3.html) each with a similar structure.

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" type="text/css">

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        width:100%; 
    }

    #mainBtn, #helpBtn, #backBtn {
        width:50px;
        height:10px;
        padding:2px 10px 10px 10px;
        color:#FFF;
    }

    #contentBox {
        width:80%;
        height:500px;
        margin:15px auto;   
    }

    #page1 #contentBox {
        background-color:aqua;
    }

    #page2 #contentBox {
        background-color:yellow;
    }

    #page3 #contentBox {
        background-color:grey;
    }
</style>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">   
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
     <a id="mainBtn" href="page2.html" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"></a>
     <h3>page 1</h3>
     <a id="helpBtn" href="page3.html" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"></a> 
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div id="contentBox">
        Some Content Here
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1',  function() {
        addBtnText();
    });

</script>

 </div><!-- /page -->

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page2">   
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
     <a id="backBtn" href="page1.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"></a>
     <h3>page 2</h3>
     <a id="helpBtn" href="page3.html" data-transition="slide" data-inline="true"></a> 
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div id="contentBox">
        Some Content Here
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page2',  function() {
        addBtnText();
    });

</script>

 </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Page3.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page3">   
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-id="etHdr" data-theme="b">
     <a id="backBtn" href="page1.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"></a>
     <h3>page 3</h3>
     <a id="mainBtn" href="page2.html" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"></a> 
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">
    <div id="contentBox">
        Some Content Here
    </div>
</div><!-- /content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page3',  function() {
        addBtnText();
    });

</script>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

And I also have an app.js file that contains the function **addBtnText()**

**App.js**

```
function addBtnText() {
//buttons
$("#backBtn").html('back');
$("#mainBtn").html('main');
$("#helpBtn").html('help');
}
```

So in theory, what I expected this to do is before each page is loaded, is to run the addBtnText function, which in turn adds the text labels to the buttons.

It works as expected on page1, and on page2, works 50% (loads the back button text, but not the help button text), and doesn't load at all on page 3 (no back or main button text).

I'm completely puzzled why it works fine on page 1, but not correctly on 2 or at all on 3.

Am I missing something important here in the splitting of pages and calling of functions?

Thanks!

Comment: buttons have the same id, so there might be a conflict. try this `$("#backBtn", this).html('back');` or `$.mobile.activePage.find("#backBtn").html('back');` to specify in which page the function should be executed since all pages will be loaded into DOM.

Comment: That was exactly it. Good catch Omar... I was in the mindset of tradiational web pages, where each page is separate, but because they all get loaded into the DOM via jquery, yes, there was a conflict with ID's... thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my problem was, and Omar's comment was right on the money. I was having an ID conflict, as I was thinking about traditional web pages (which are separate), vs jquery's loading of the pages into the DOM. There was an ID conflict, and as soon as I changed the ID's to classes on the buttons, everything works as expected.

Thanks for the heads up Omar.